# Pumping Lemma - non regular

Tags: regular-language, pumping-lemma

Can everyone help me to show that:

the language

$$L = \{a,b\}^* \setminus \{a^m b^{2m} a^n\mid m,n \ge 0\}$$

is not regular.

I don't know what is the meaning for the proof.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: If $L$ were regular, its complement would also be regular. (If you’ve not yet proved this, you should do so; it can be done quite easily in terms of DFAs.) Its complement is

$$\left\{a^mb^{2m}a^n:m,n\ge 0\right\}\;,$$

and it’s very straightforward to use the pumping lemma to prove that this is not regular. In fact, the argument is very similar to the [example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages#Use_of_lemma) used in the Wikipedia article.

Comment: i have proved the {a^m b^2m a^n : m,n≥0} part for using pumping lemma. But how to rely on this part from the previous {a,b}*. I am confused how to show them together

Comment: @CKL: Have you learned about regular languages and finite state automata? Because that’s probably the easiest way to show that the complement of a regular language is regular. Once you know that, you know that if $L$ were regular, $\{a,b\}^*\setminus L$ would be regular. But $\{a,b\}^*\setminus L$ is $\left\{a^mb^{2m}a^n:m,n\ge 0\right\}$, which we know is *not* regular, so $L$ cannot be regular either.

Comment: Yes, i have learned. But i still can't understand how to prove it. Do you have any example for prove format.